# Video / Voice Chat Web Application with Java

Tags: java, audio, video, chat

I am trying to add a voice / video chat feature to my web-based chat application developed in JavaEE.
I have not found any tutorials on how to achieve that with both Server and Client written in Java (no javascript allowed).

Is there any tutorials that can help me (using websockets for example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check out the [github project Jitsi](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi). I don't know exactly what tech they are using, but there is a Java version and the code is available for inspection. They may have a forum. I have only taken a cursory look but was reminded of the project by your question.